# How can I specify img <header> tag inline?

Tags: css, html, header, background-image

I am using this bootstrap one page wonder template and develop sinatra web site.

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-one-page-wonder/

I would like to change img in  for every time accessing this site.

So I commented out .header-image in  CSS file.

```
/*background: url('http://placehold.it/1900x500') no-repeat center center scroll;*/
```

and I write in html file.
Within header tag ,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
```

And add this.

```
<header class="header-image"　style="background: url('http://placehold.it/1900x500') no-repeat center center scroll;">
```

But it won't work. How can I specify background img in inline header tag ?

Comment: It worked for me when i added inline style to header tag using developer tool in chrome. Can you add a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Give overflow auto to body this is because IE takes body height as 100% by default ad margin inside it extends its height so to change its default behavior u can use overflow auto !

```
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: black;
font-size: 2em;
color: white;   
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Well I tried safari and chrome but same result.So to try to figure out, I added attribute one by one in style , and if I changed order like "no-repeat scroll center center" then it worked. I don't know why..